# VSTO - how to show shape before event handler finishes execution

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, shapes

I am writing a COM level addin to excel. In my code I am handling a sheet selection change. When the selection change happens I have the following code:

```
Shapes.AddShape(DefaultShape, Left, Top, Width, Height);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
DefaultShape.Delete
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a shape show itself for two seconds and then disappear. What actually happens is that the shape doesn't show up at all because the gui doesn't show any changes until the event handler finishes execution. Does anyone know how I can tell excel to show the shape before it waits?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to start a new thread and sleep / delete in the new thread.